# ¿Qué son los atributos ARIA?

Tags: html, html5, accesibilidad

En muchas páginas web y en bastantes preguntas de StackOverflow se pueden encontrar atributos que comienzan con `aria-` y están relacionados con accesibilidad. Por ejemplo:

```
<div class="text">
    <label id="tp1-label" for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" size="20"
           aria-labelledby="tp1-label"
           aria-describedby="tp1"
           aria-required="true" />
    <div id="tp1" class="tooltip"
         role="tooltip"
         aria-hidden="true">El nombre es obligatorio</div>
</div>
```

¿Qué son y para que sirven los atributos `aria-*`? ¿Cuántos hay y cuáles son los más importantes? ¿Y por qué deberían usarse?

Comment: Gracias a tus preguntas investigo y aprendo más :p

Answer (score 31, accepted):

ARIA significa **Accessible Rich Internet Applications**, es una especificación técnica cuyo objetivo es aumentar la accesibilidad de los contenidos dinámicos y de los componentes de interfaces dinámicas desarrollados con HTML, JavaScript, Ajax y tecnologías asociadas.

ARIA describe como agregar la semántica y metadatos al contenido HTML con el fin de hacer que los controles de interfaz y los contenidos dinámicos sean más accesibles, especialmente para personas con alguna discapacidad.

**[Referencia](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/introduction#intro_ria_accessibility)**

---

Los atributos `aria-*` sirven para agregar información semántica a los elementos de un sitio web, especìficamente propiedades y estados (los cuales forman parte de los roles), los cuales pueden:

- Informar el estado o las acciones de un elemento de la interfaz gráfica.
- Indicar que el contenido de una sección puede cambiar cuando hay interacción por parte del usuario, por ejemplo cuando se hace "focus".
- Informar si hay elementos que forman parte de una interfaz "drag-and-drop", explicando el rol de cada elemento.
- Indicar relaciones o asociaciones entre elementos del documento, las cuales no pueden ser determinadas según la estructura del mismo.

**[Referencia](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties)**

---

La lista de los atributos `aria-*` es la siguiente:

- aria-activedescendant
- aria-atomic
- aria-autocomplete
- aria-busy (estado)
- aria-checked (estado)
- aria-controls
- aria-describedby
- aria-disabled (estado)
- aria-dropeffect
- aria-expanded (estado)
- aria-flowto
- aria-grabbed (estado)
- aria-haspopup
- aria-hidden (estado)
- aria-invalid (estado)
- aria-label
- aria-labelledby
- aria-level
- aria-live
- aria-multiline
- aria-multiselectable
- aria-orientation
- aria-owns
- aria-posinset
- aria-pressed (estado)
- aria-readonly
- aria-relevant
- aria-required
- aria-selected (estado)
- aria-setsize
- aria-sort
- aria-valuemax
- aria-valuemin
- aria-valuenow
- aria-valuetext

**[Referencia](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties)**

---

Para decir cuales son los atributos más importantes creo que es un poco subjetivo, no existe una referencia o recomendación oficial y considero que es mejor ver la compatibilidad que ofrecen o no los dispositivos como los lectores de pantallas, teclados Braille, etc.

*[Aquí dejo un enlace](http://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/aria/)* actualizado constantemente que muestra la compatibilidad de algunos atributos ARIA con los distintos lectores de pantalla que existen.

---

Los atributos ARIA deberíamos utilizarlos para que las personas que tienen  (tenemos) alguna discapacidad puedan navegar y entender fácilmente la estructura de los sitios web que implementamos/desarrollamos/creamos.

Entre los dispositivos para personas con discapacidad están:

- Apuntadores
- Conmutadores
- Lectores de pantalla
- OCR
- Teclados

En *[este enlace en inglés](https://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/people-use-web/stories)* hay algunas historias de como algunas personas con discapacidad utilizar la web y que herramientas podemos usar para que estas personas puedan navegar mejor por nuestros sitios web.

Answer (score 4):

Quizá no sea tomada como respuesta pero *[este articulo](https://www.marcozehe.de/2014/03/27/what-is-wai-aria-what-does-it-do-for-me-and-what-not/)* puede ayudar(en inglés) 
para conocer y comprender el estándar `WAI-ARIA`

En conclusión

**¿Qué es ?**

Se trata de un conjunto de atributos para ayudar a mejorar la semántica de un sitio web o una aplicación web para ayudar a las ayudas técnicas, tales como lectores de pantalla para ciegos, dar sentido a ciertas cosas que no son nativos de HTML.

**[¿sobre su uso?](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#notes-on-aria-use-in-html)**

Answer (score 0):

[Este artículo](https://htmldesdecero.es/blog/que-es-marcado-wai-aria/) pude ayudar a comprender el estándar WAI-ARIA.

**¿Qué es ARIA?**

ARIA es la abreviatura de Accessible Rich Internet Applications. ARIA es un conjunto de atributos que puede agregar a los elementos HTML que definen formas de hacer que el contenido web y las aplicaciones sean accesibles para los usuarios con discapacidades que usan tecnologías de asistencia (AT). Cuando los problemas de accesibilidad no se pueden gestionar con HTML nativo, ARIA puede ayudar a cerrar esas brechas.

**¿Cuántos hay y cuáles son los más importantes?**

Estás son todos los roles en una imagen. Además de roles, cuenta con estados y propiedades.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para obtener más información, consulta la [documentación oficial de WAI-ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/) o la [Introducción a ARIA de Google.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-aria/)

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Guiño: mostrás en una imagen los roles, ¿y si alguien con lector de pantalla desea conocer el contenido de la imagen? :) Lee [answer].